# Selenium Webdriver: Pressing some key after determinate character appears when writing

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium webdriver to write text using the following code

```
def typing(self, text):
    time.sleep(1)
    for character in text:
        actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        actions.send_keys(character)
        actions.perform()
```

Basically what it does is that it inputs some text and writes it, but I have to add a special characteristic: When characters `"@"` or `"&"` are present it has to count the next words until it finds a space `" "`, and just before it, press enter key.

In this case I configured a function `press_enter()` so this part will be easy.

Some examples:

> @eat_pizza(press enter here) every day
>
> I think &guacamole(press enter here) is good for health
>
> &my_wife_Charlotte(press enter here) is so nice @fantastic(press enter
> here) and amazing

Comment: try replacing " " with "\n" sometimes that acts as enter

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

```
new_text = []
text = 'I think &guacamole is good for health'.split(' ')
# text is ['I', 'think', '&guacamole', 'is', 'good', 'for', 'health']
for word in text:
    if word.startswith('@') or word.startswith('&'):
        word += u' \ue007'
    new_text.append(word)

# new_text is ['I', 'think', u'&guacamole \ue007', 'is', 'good', 'for', 'health']
new_text = ' '.join(new_text)
# new_text is u'I think &guacamole \ue007 is good for health'
```

Your method will now look like this

```
def typing(self, text):
    time.sleep(1)
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.send_keys(text)
    actions.perform()
```

You can send the whole text at the time and each time on `u' \ue007'` (the same as `Keys.ENTER`) Enter should be triggered

**UPDATE**

```
new_text = []
text = 'I think &guacamole is good for health'.split(' ')
# text is ['I', 'think', '&guacamole', 'is', 'good', 'for', 'health']
for word in text:
    new_text.append(word)
    if word.startswith('@') or word.startswith('&'):
        new_text.append(press_enter)

def typing(self, text):
    time.sleep(1)
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    for word in new_text:
        if not isinstance(word, str):
            word()
        else:
            actions.send_keys(text)
            actions.perform()
```

Comment: Could I add a function to the list, for example ['I', 'think', '&guacamole', press_enter(), 'is'...]  ?

Comment: @TheDan check updated answer. Is this what you mean?

Comment: The good thing is that it is pressing enter, but It is giving me this weird result:

 nk &guacamole is good for healthI think &guacamole is good for healthI think &guacamole is good for healthI think &guacamole is good for healthI think

Comment: @TheDan what do you mean by "result"? Can you point on the line that works incorrectly?